# Divergence theorem and continuity equation

Tags: divergence-operator

A steady $1D$ flow field is flowing within a pipe in the $x$-direction.

Starting with
the continuity equation
$$\dfrac {d \rho}{dt} + ∇ · (\rho u) = 0$$
where $u = u \underline i + v \underline j + w \underline k$, and using the divergence theorem, show that this leads
to the expression $ \rho uA$ = constant where $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the pipe
in the $y − z$ plane

I'm struggling with this and some help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the cross section constant?

Comment: yes it is, sorry for that

Comment: Well, in that case $\rho$ is constant, so $\partial \rho/\partial t = 0$, therefore $\rho {\bf u} $ is also constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

steady $\implies \frac {d\rho}{dt}=0$

divergence theorem is

$$\int\int\int \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec {u})=$$
$$\int\int \rho \vec { u}\cdot\vec {n}ds=0 $$